# Fix the width of a single column for a table chart in Superset

Tags: css, apache-superset

I am using Superset visualization tool to build a chart using Table chart.I want to fix the width of 1 particular column in the table chart.
How can I achieve the same? I tried using css code but it does not work for a single/particular column.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply CSS to specific column of table you could use `nth-child`

For example:

```css
col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 340px;
  background-color: #f67171;
}
```

This part will set width of background colour of only first column.

You can read more about usage of nth-child [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)